# Is there any way to install windows server 2003 on 16GB flash memory?

Tags: windows, portable

Is there any way to install windows server 2003 on 16GB flash memory to have a portable server? I don't want use it as server. I tried to install it using Portable-VirtualBox. but it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Windows Server 2003 requires more then 16GB to be installed.

Comment: Thanks.then how can i install windows server 2003 on 500GB external H.D.D and run it in windows xp? like vmware installed on it.

Comment: Just create a Virtual Machine on the 500GB hdd